# Using Expect for Chai in Javascript

Tags: javascript, chai, expect

I'm having issues with trying to use expect().to.throw()

For the code

```
var expect = chai.expect();


  it('has a prefix of 51 and a length of 16', function() {
    expect(detectNetwork('5112345678901234')).to.throw(('MasterCard'));
  });
  it('has a prefix of 52 and a length of 16', function() {
    expect(detectNetwork('5212345678901234')).to.equal(('MasterCard'));
  });
  it('has a prefix of 53 and a length of 16', function() {
    expect(detectNetwork('5312345678901234')).to.equal(('MasterCard'));
  });
```

In the same file, I've had no issues with

```
  var should = chai.should();
```

```
TypeError: expect is not a function
```

I tried changing the implementation of expect to

var expect = require('chai').expect

and tried different types of expect statements that sometimes produced expect().to.equal() is not a function

Answer (score 0):

you should write like this and you don't call it

```js
const expect = require("chai").expect;
```